# How to define user input as dd/mm/yyyy and error handle input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble coding the user input variable DOB as a while loop and showing an error if the user does not input dob as dd/mm/yyyy

Any suggestions?

```
import datetime

while True :
    DOB = input('Date of Birth ')
    try :
        DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(DOB, "%d//%m//%Y")
    except ValueError:
        print ('Error, Please try again')
    else:
        print("Error: must be format dd/mm/yyyy ")
        userkey = input("press 1 to try again or 0 to exit:")
        if userkey == "1":
            header()
        else:
            sys.exit
```

Comment: Why are you escaping forward slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of errors here. So bear with me if I seem to be overwhelmingly negative.

```
DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(week, "%d//%m//%Y")
```

is expecting the input string to be in `week`, but the `input()` call actually assigns it to `DOB`. So you will get `NameError: name 'week' is not defined`. And you have specified the date format with doubled slashes, `%d//%m//%Y`, as if the slashes needed to be escaped, but they don't, so you are asking the user to enter `12//02//2018` which no user is likely to guess, especially as your error prompt does not say this.

Next, you have `try..except..else`. This doesn't do what you seem to think it does. From the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

> The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code
>   that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

In other words, even if the user *does* succeed in entering a "valid" date, double slashes and all, your code issues the message `Error: must be format dd/mm/yyyy`.

After that, if the user makes an error and presses `1` to try again, your exception handler calls `header()`, which doesn't exist, and so the program will fail. And if the user presses `0` your exception handler attempts to call `sys.exit()`, but there is no `import sys`, so that will also get a `NameError`. And if even with `import sys`, it will still not do what you want, because you omitted the parens. Without them, you are *naming* the function, not *calling* it.

And lastly, you have a `while True` loop but you never exit from it, even if the user does enter a valid date.

With all of these things fixed up, the code looks like this:

```
import datetime
import sys

while True :
    DOB = input('Date of Birth ')
    try :
        DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(DOB, "%d/%m/%Y")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: must be format dd/mm/yyyy ")
        userkey = input("press 1 to try again or 0 to exit:")
        if userkey == "0":
            sys.exit()

print (f"DOB is {DOB}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would replacing (f"DOB is {DOB}") with break close the while loop and enable me to start another while loop ?

Comment: If you put a `break` where the `print()` call is you will get a syntax error. You can only use `break` inside a loop. It is already outside the loop. I put the `print()` call there only to verify program operation. Without it you can't see if the program ended because of the `break` or because of `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the input as variable `DOB` but using variable `week` while testing against the given format inside `datetime.datetime.strptime`:

```
DOB = input('Date of Birth ')
DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(week, "%d//%m//%Y")
```

So, you can do:

```
DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(DOB, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Also, make the datetime format specifier as `%d/%m/%Y`, without the redundant `/`s in between.

Another thing is, you have not imported `sys` but used `sys.exit` at the end. So you need to:

- `import sys`
- Use exit status you want in the function call e.g. `sys.exit(0)` (the default is `0` BTW when no integer is given) for exit status `0` (means success, anything else indicates failure: typically between 1-255). Just doing `sys.call` refers to the function object, does not call it

As a side note, as your `DOB` is not a constant, you should make it *snake_case* e.g.:

```
date_of_birth = input('Date of Birth ')
```

Comment: also, `sys.exit` should be called as `sys.exit(0)` and `import sys` is required at the top.

Comment: @Devstr Edited in.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have edited the code (pasted into question area) but now get an error when I enter the date in the correct format. I have tried cmd and spyder.   Date of Birth 10/10/1985
Error: must be format dd/mm/yyyy
press 1 to try again or 0 to exit: